# "Conflict" with jQuery (or its plugins)?

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript

I've been working on localhost and everything looks fine but then when I uploaded my Wordpress theme online, all of the jQuery plugin functions are undefined!

One solution that worked (which I haven't tested a lot so I still don't know if it will work in the long run) is to import the javascript file from the plugin's main website or github page. I don't really prefer this "solution."

Another is the solution [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-is-not-working-in-wordpress-solution/) but I haven't tested this a lot also. My issue here is I've used jQuery in another theme and everything works using just `$`, but in my new theme it doesn't work with `$` and so I have to use `$j` instead. It's just that I'm very used to using just `$`.

Can someone explain this weird phenomenon? Thank you! :)

Comment: Do test the solution you linked to yourself?.. :) Using just `$` for jQuery is not supported in WordPress.

Comment: Is jQuery itself loading when your theme is "live"?

Comment: What's the site URL? (So we can see the errors). How are you calling the main jQuery library: via wp_enqueue_script in functions.php or by a simple link in header.php?

Comment: Also, do look up how JS closures work. Always use closures. That fixes your problems and many other JS oddities in one simple step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$` but it is advised you don't. Use `jQuery` or something like the example in your link, if you must use `$` you can do so like this;

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
   //$ will cause problems if put here:)
```

To use it for just a function you can append jQuery to the end like:

```
(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() 
})(jQuery);  //dont forget this part
```

Comment: How about functions outside, do I pass $ as an argument as well?

Comment: To use `$` in this case it must be inside a functions defined as `function($)` , anything outside that will cause a conflict. But you can use it for any functions if you also append jQuery to the end, Ill edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because WordPress loads jQuery in "no conflict" mode.

I'm also in the habit of using `$`, and there's a fairly simple solution. Just modify your `(document).ready` function like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

For more info, check out [the Codex section on this topic](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers).